# Google Drive Android API in Google Play Services 4.1

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I read [article](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.cz/2014/01/introducing-google-drive-android-api.html) about new Google Drive Android API in Google Play Services 4.1. This is already available for download in SDK. But only problem is API description. I found only "old" API [description](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started).

I am looking for any information how to implement new "Transparent use and syncing of local storage".

***Transparent use and syncing of local storage***

*The Google Drive Android API temporarily uses a local data store in case the device is not connected to a network. So, no need to worry about failed API calls in your app because the user is offline or experiencing a network connectivity problem. Data stored locally in this fashion will automatically and transparently be stored in the Google Drive cloud by Android’s sync scheduler when connectivity is available to minimize impact on battery life, bandwidth, and other resources.*

Answer (score 1):

I have just put some code on GitHub.
https://github.com/seanpjanson/140201-GDAA
If you're on Windows / Eclipse environment, you may benefit from the 'readme.txt' file.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to implement it soon : )

Answer (score 0):

@Michal
Your description link is correct. If you dig deeper you will find full bunch of links from there.

1. The Github Quickstart has functional code you can use
2. Github "android-demos" is functional as well and has most of the scenarios covered (https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos)
3. reference is here (https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/package-summary.html)

I've been using these resources for a week now and managed to get up-and-running. There are a few hurdles when setting up the environment in Eclipse (I run WIN 7) and it was a real pain. I will have a bit more info together in a few days and will publish it.

Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with Google, just a poor developer like yourself. Don't shoot :)  Hell I'm not even a developer.